# I am having more characters in the file that I am writing in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I am writing to a file using `ofstream` in C++. Each line has to have a relative time, a comma, and the value that I am writing. The values are `std::vector<unsigned char>` in order to write any value that I want and to read back in another method. My test is writing 3 values. The first value is concatenated to a weird byte on the end, even if I use `\0` or `\n`. But the other 2 values are fine.

This is the output file:

```
0,BAC�
1000,DEF
2000,GHI
```

And the second problem is when I read the values. I don't know how to set dynamically an array to read only the values that are written on the line and compare to the previous char vector that I wrote before.

Header file:

```
class SensorRecorder {
private:
    std::ofstream outFile;
    std::ifstream infile;
    std::string path;
    long duration = -1;
public:
    const std::string OUTPUT_DIR = "out";
    const std::string EXTENSION = ".out";
    const char SEPARATOR = ',';
    SensorRecorder(const char *classNameType);
    ~SensorRecorder();
    int write(std::vector<unsigned char> value);
    std::vector<unsigned char> read(long relativeTime);
    void close();
    std::string getFileName();
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "utils/SensorRecorder.h"
#include "utils/DateTools.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

SensorRecorder::SensorRecorder(const char *classNameType) {
    boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
    full_path.append(OUTPUT_DIR, boost::filesystem::path::codecvt());
    if (boost::filesystem::create_directory(full_path)) {
        std::cout << "Directory Created: " << full_path << std::endl;
    }
    std::string fileName = classNameType + ((std::string) "-") + DateTools::getPlainDate() + EXTENSION;
    full_path.append(fileName, boost::filesystem::path::codecvt());
    path = full_path.c_str();
    outFile.open(path);
}
int SensorRecorder::write(std::vector<unsigned char> value) {
    if (outFile.is_open()) {
        char *data = reinterpret_cast<char *>(value.data());
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
        auto value = now_ms.time_since_epoch();

        if (duration == -1) {
            duration = 0;
        } else {
            duration = value.count() - duration;
        }
        // write in the file
        outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << data << '\0' << '\n';
        duration = value.count();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
std::vector<unsigned char> SensorRecorder::read(long relativeTime) {
    infile.open(path);
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Reading from the file" << std::endl;
        long duration;
        char comma;
        unsigned char data[300];

        while (infile >> duration >> comma >> data) {
            std::cout << "duration: " << duration << std::endl;
            std::cout << "data: " << data << std::endl;
            if (duration == relativeTime) {
                std::cout << "INSIDE " << std::endl;
                infile.close();

                // cast the value
                std::vector<unsigned char> outputValues(data, data + sizeof(data));
                return outputValues;
            }
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    return std::vector<unsigned char>();
}
```

My test:

```
TEST_F(SensorRecorderTest, TestWriteOnFile) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> inputValues01 = {'B', 'A', 'C'};
    std::vector<unsigned char> inputValues02 = {'D', 'E', 'F'};
    std::vector<unsigned char> inputValues03 = {'G', 'H', 'I'};
    mySensorRecorder = new SensorRecorder("SensorRecorderTest");

    // write on the file
    int ret = mySensorRecorder->write(inputValues01);
    ASSERT_EQ(ret, 1);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    ret = mySensorRecorder->write(inputValues02);
    ASSERT_EQ(ret, 1);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    ret = mySensorRecorder->write(inputValues03);
    ASSERT_EQ(ret, 1);

    mySensorRecorder->close();

    // read from the file
    std::vector<unsigned char> outputValues01 = mySensorRecorder->read(0);
    ASSERT_EQ(inputValues01, outputValues01);
}
```

The error:

```
Expected equality of these values:
  inputValues01
    Which is: { 'B' (66, 0x42), 'A' (65, 0x41), 'C' (67, 0x43) }
  outputValues01
    Which is: { 'B' (66, 0x42), 'A' (65, 0x41), 'C' (67, 0x43), '\xE4' (228), '\x16' (22), '\x7F' (127), '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', ... }
```

Comment: With `data` obviously being a non-null terminated string, `outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << data << '\0' << '\n';` is ***not*** how you go about writing a null-terminated string to an output stream. You obviously recognize that `data` must be null-terminated, for it to be properly written as a C-style string, but this is not how you go about doing that. You have to append the `'\0'` to `data` itself, then write just the `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the write method to not convert vector to char array and afterward I just `push_back` the `\0` character.

```
int SensorRecorder::write(std::vector<unsigned char> value) {
    if (outFile.is_open()) {
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
        auto v = now_ms.time_since_epoch();

        if (duration == -1) {
            duration = 0;
        } else {
            duration = v.count() - duration;
        }
        // write in the file
        value.push_back('\0');

        std::cout << value.size() << " " << value.data() << std::endl;
        outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << value.data() << '\n';

        // evaluate duration time to the next write
        duration = v.count();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "error writing..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is null terminated strings.

```
char *data = reinterpret_cast<char *>(value.data());
outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << data << '\0' << '\n';
```

The contract of a char* on its own is that it ends with a `\0` (to know how many characters to write, strlen will look up the first available `\0`). In your case, it doesn't. You should use a real string, or at least use:

```
outFile << duration << SEPARATOR << std::string(data, data+3) << '\n';
```

Adding a `\0` on this instruction will not make the string null terminated by magic. You have to keep the size.

(read has the same flaw).